# GWT changing style during drag event takes too long

Tags: performance, events, gwt, drag-and-drop, tree

It's my first question here, and i'm not an english native speaker, so i apologize in advance, if that makes my explainations difficult to understand.

### CONTEXT

I'm in charge of the developpement of a small application which manipulate vocabulary sets.
The application is built on GWT, added by GWT-Bootstrap and some other libraries, that have nothing to do with the ui part of the application. 
To expose to the user the terms of this vocabulary, i use a tree stucture, visually speaking.

### STORY

The tree has few requirements, it has to allow drag&drop features for his items and show connectors between them.

I started by using the Tree ui class from the native GWT components. It turned out that with a lot of terms loaded in the tree, the performances felt down, even in production mode.

I decided so to try the CellTree implementation, but it didn't fit for me since make disappear the "showmore" button is not an easy task, and styling the tree too.

I finally ends up with my own implementation of a tree, from scratch.
This implementation relies essentially on a simple html list structure (ul-li), and benefits at maximum of css capabilities. Indeed, expanding a tree node is done with css, using a trick known as "checkbox hack".

At this point the custom implementation of the tree is fast (better than tree or celltree), even populated with thousands items, and it met the requirements, but...

### THE ISSUE

When an item is being dragged over other items, the style of those items change depending on dropping possibilities.

#### 1st Solution

The first idea was to benefit of the css, and use the :hover selector to change the style of the items, depending on their classes.
But there is a major issue in current browsers (specifically Chrome), which make the css :hover not triggered, if the mouse left button is down, which it's the case when you drag something (chromium issue 122746)

It seems that i have to forgot an exculsive css solution, until the :hover triggering issue will be closed.

#### 2nd solution

The only other solution to which i came by is to change the style of the item programmatically.

Code of the handler

```
@Override
public void onDragEnter(DragEnterEvent event)
{
    if (event.getSource() instanceof Word)
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        Word word = (Word) event.getSource();
        word.addStyleDependentName("over");
    }
}
@Override
public void onDragLeave(DragLeaveEvent event)
{
    if (event.getSource() instanceof Word)
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        Word word = (Word) event.getSource();
        word.removeStyleDependentName("over");
    }
}
```

It works fine with a few items, but when dealing with thousands it make the application freezing, and the rendering is somehow random.

### PRECISIONS

The issue appears when dealing with 5000 items in the tree (the application must handle such dataset).

I'm aware of efficient events handling concerns, as event bubbling, and the handler is unique as it is recommanded when the number of potential handlers, if made specific for each item, is a factor of lack of performance as the number of items increase.

Secondary i've used the speed tracer to analyse the source of the problem, **and it turned out something i don't understand**:

Events are incredibly slow on top elements of the tree, specifically the paint event which take 1 second to be fired after the style recalculation
[Slow events Speed Tracer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvhka.png)

Events speed is fair enougth on bottom elements of the tree
[Fair enougth speed events Speed Tracer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cb4m.png)

### QUESTION

I'm stuck with this issue since few days, and i wonder if someone could point out what i am missing.
Perhaps, the behaviour is totally normal, but maybe there is a workaround for a such issue ?
I'll be glad if someone could help me on this point.

Thanks you for any reply !

lilBrain

Comment: +1 for the beautiful formatting

Comment: Have you found any solution? Do you have any sample code elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [GWT-Dnd](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/) please have a look at that;

[Slow drag performance when there are a lot of draggables on screen](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gwt-dnd/USvr-f4NvO0/DtLEC_gUYioJ)

It's mentioned that this performance issue is related to finding x, y coordinates of the widget on a drop event.

`com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.client.DropControllerCollection.getIntersectDropController(int   x, int y)`

there is a block of code that loops through the DropController candidates with what appears it's only purpose being for debugging.

```
for (int i = sortedCandidates.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   Candidate candidate = sortedCandidates[i];
   if (DOMUtil.DEBUG) {
      DOMUtil.debugWidgetWithColor(candidate.getDropTarget(), "blue");
   }
}
```

subsequent to that, the code then loops through and actually tries to
identify if the x and y coordinates are over a DropController.

Hope this will help you.